# Split string type list into Sub list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have create String list as follow

```
List("[MSC050,176484]", "[MSC050,176486]")
```

I try to convert this list into sub list as following code. I think it is way to achieve my task.

```
input.map(_.substring(5,13))
```

Then I got list as follow

```
List(50,17648, 50,17648)
```

I want to get list as follow

```
List(50176484, 50176486)
```

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to simply remove all commas from your substring.

```
input.map(_.substring(5,13).replaceAll(",",""))
// res0: List[String] = List(5017648, 5017648)
```

Comment: Thank you given me valuable time to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you meant this:

```
List(("MSC050",176484), ("MSC050",176486))
```

i.e a list of pairs of type (String, Int). If that's so, then the answer would be:

```
list.map(p => p._1.takeRight(3) + p._2)
```

_1 and _2 are the elements of the tuple. In this case _1 refers to the String and _2 refers to the Int

---Edit

Since you've clarified how the list looks like, then the answer would be:

```
list.map(_.foldLeft("")((newString, currentChar) => if(currentChar.isDigit) newString + currentChar else newString))
```

If what you are looking for is to preserve the digits only. FoldLeft traverses the String and at the same time it creates a new string, what I am basically telling it is that if the current char is a digit then add it to the new string, if not simply continue traversing the old string without modifying the new one.

Comment: my list look like {List("[MSC050,176484]", "[MSC050,176486]")}

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a more generic approach like this:

```
import scala.util.matching
val pattern = raw"(\d+)".r
val result = List("[MSC050,176484]", "[MSC050,176486]").map(pattern.findAllIn(_).mkString("")).map(_.toLong)
```

It removes al the characters that are not digits and then convert the List[String] to a List[Long].